# Caching API or store data in Vue CLI PWA

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, caching, axios

**Updated**
The issue was to manipulate the register service worker file, instead of configuring the service worker in vue.config.js like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    workboxPluginMode: "GenerateSW",
    workboxOptions: {
      navigateFallback: "/index.html",
      runtimeCaching: [{
        urlPattern: new RegExp('APU_URL'),
        handler: 'networkFirst',
        options: {
          networkTimeoutSeconds: 20,
          cacheName: 'api-cache',
          cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [0, 200],
          },
        },
      }]
    }

  }
};
```

**Original**
TL;DR Trying to cache axios data for offline use in vue app

I'm trying out some PWA options for my Vue CLI app, where I'm wondering if it's possible to cache vuex states, in order to still display data from my API call on the site?

Otherwise, I've tried my way to cache the api call itself by using the following code in my registerServiceWorker.js file:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    //Basic service worker content
  })
}

self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  e.waitUntil(caches.open('apiname')
    .then(cache => cache.add(`${'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'}APIURL`)))
})
```

In my store.js file, I have the loaded API setting the data to the "games" state:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(axios)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    games: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_GAMES(state, payload) {
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.name < b.name) return -1
        if (a.name > b.name) return 1
        return 0
      }
      state.games = payload.sort(compare)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    loadGames({
      commit
    }) {
      axios.get(`${'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'}API_URL`)
        .then(r => {
          commit('SET_GAMES', r.data)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log('Axios api error: ', e)
        })
    }
  },
  getters: {
    clickedGame(state) {
      return (id) => {
        return state.games.find((game) => {
          return game.id == id
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" url before the API URL is to fix CORS blocking the api call.

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to inserting the event listener, but the general idea is to cache the api data, in order for the app to function offline with the data.

I believe I need to update the data as well somehow, if there's new data to display form the API call. But I also get the feeling that the service worker handles this by itself, from what I've seen in the console.